# Is it possible developing a evolution (mail client) plugin in Java?

Tags: java, mono

I have to write a plugin for [Evolution](http://projects.gnome.org/evolution/) and I'm studying the different possibilities. The documentation says that eplugin feature is independent from the language you choose but I've only seen Evolution plugins developed in plain C and a few in C#/Mono.

I suppose that It's not possible using Sun VM because of GTK.
Am I wrong?

And, what about Java/Mono using [IKVM](http://www.ikvm.net/)? Is it possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what was your experience with that did you sucesseded , i am making that eperiment as well and i would appreciate any feedback from your side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've dug myself part way through the Evolution Plugin documentation, and while they're a bit coy about it, I'm given to believe that their interface mechanisms are rather C-centric.

This means you could write plugins in Lua, Python, Perl, probably Ruby and many other languages that support C-style interfaces. There's a chance that you could do it from Java using the JNI (Java Native Interface) mechanism, though chances are you'd do a lot of type translating and data copying along the way.

Let's say it might be possible to do in Java if you really, really wanted to; but it would be painful. I wouldn't recommend it.

You might consider building a plugin in a more C compatible language and then let it do TCP/IP I/O over sockets with a Java app that presents the pretty GUI and does the heavy lifting.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm checking a evolution C# sample http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2007/Oct-04-1.html and I'll try to do the same using Java (IKVM). I think that It should work.